# MySQL fetch and insert where value is

Tags: mysql, sql

I am new to MySQL, so I'll explain by example.

I have 2 tables:

```
Admins(
id int auto_increment not null,
primary key(id)
);

Users(
admin_id int not null,
id varchar(255) not null,
password varchar(255) not null
);
```

I basically create an entry for a admin, then I want the admin to be able to add users that are tied to his ID, so then I can also read all users tied to that certain admin (the id and password parameters, to be exact)

I cannot figure out the syntax for how to do this, could anyone provide some help? Maybe there is a way to just write all that data straight in the admin table somehow so I don't have to use 2 tables?

I use PHP to do everything, by the way

Comment: `I want the admin to be able to add users that are tied to his ID`, can you explain what you meant by `tied to his id`. Are you looking for `Foreign key relationship`?

Comment: you have to use `INNER JOIN` query with `WHERE` Clause

Comment: By that I meant that the users are part of that certain admin, as if an entire list of user tables was part of the admin table. I googled `foreign key relationship` and after skimming it I believe that's what I'm looking for

Comment: what does your title means `MySQL fetch and insert where value is`

Comment: My title is a little weird as I dont know the correct terminology, I meant to fetch values from and insert values into a table where another value is a certain number. I explained further with my example. I think you and harish pointed me in the right way, though, I may be able to get it to function on my own